# Increase stack size in OS X Lion

Tags: g++, stack, osx-lion

I need to do it for a C++ program that needs a lot of stack. I use g++ (included in OS X Lion) to compile it. How could I increase it for my program?

Comment: You can do that with ulimit -s.

Comment: I can not: sudo ulimit -s 128000
/usr/bin/ulimit: line 4: ulimit: stack size: cannot modify limit: Invalid argument

Comment: This can help - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1419/_index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1419/_index.html

Using gcc, pass link flags through to ld with -Wl:

```
gcc -Wl,-stack_size -Wl,1000000 foo.c
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getrlimit`/`setrlimit` - this works on Linux, Mac OS X, and other POSIX-ish operating systems, e.g.

```
#include <sys/resource.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    const rlim_t kStackSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024;   // min stack size = 16 MB
    struct rlimit rl;
    int result;

    result = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        if (rl.rlim_cur < kStackSize)
        {
            rl.rlim_cur = kStackSize;
            result = setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rl);
            if (result != 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "setrlimit returned result = %d\n", result);
            }
        }
    }

    // ...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in OS X Lion, I can not set more than 32 * 1024 * 1024, but in Linux I can set even 256 * 1024 * 1024 , which is what I need. So my problem is how to surpass that limit in OS X using that code

Comment: Well even 32 MB is a **huge** stack - if you really need a 256 MB stack then I think it's probably time to re-evaluate your program design.

Comment: I agree with what you say. the problem is that the program is not mines and I have to work with it and now, it is impossible to modify it

Comment: in other words "eat other's dogwood" :-P

Comment: There are some quick and easy fixes for this type of problem, e.g. if the routines with the large local variables are only used in a single thread then you can just make the largest locals `static`.