# How do I increase the stack size when compiling with Clang on OS X?

Tags: macos, ld, compiler-options, stack-size

Can I specify the stack size with clang++?  I can't find any compiler options that would allow me to do so. I'm using OS X.

Note: This question specifically refers to Clang, not the GCC compiler.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase stack size in OS X Lion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214363/increase-stack-size-in-os-x-lion)

Comment: @Kiran: You'll notice that that question refers to a different compiler.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The linker, rather than the compiler, is responsible for setting the stack size of the main thread. The man page for `ld` contains the following:

```
-stack_size size
    Specifies the maximum stack size for the main thread in a program. Without this
    option a program has a 8MB stack. The argument size is a hexadecimal number with
    an optional leading 0x. The size should be an even multiple of 4KB, that is the
    last three hexadecimal digits should be zero.
```

For instance, to specify a 16MB stack you could do the following:

```
mrowe@apollo:~$ cc -Wl,-stack_size -Wl,0x1000000 -o test test.m
mrowe@apollo:~$ otool -lV test | grep stack
 stacksize 16777216
```

Note the `-Wl,` prefix on the arguments passed to `cc` to have it pass them on to the linker.

Comment: does this answer still holds true up to this date? I was also curious on how to increase the compiled program in clang.

Comment: Also isn't that the modern versions of clang used a different linker now?

Comment: It still works exactly the same with the most recently-released beta versions of Xcode.