# How to increase stack size under OS X using LLVM tool chain?

Tags: c, macos, stack

Under MSVC, we could use

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/STACK:0x10000000")
```

to have a stack of 256MB. Is there any approach to get a larger stack under OS X? I'm using LLVM tool chain.

Comment: What does your linker documentation say?

Comment: ulimit -s 8192 will set the stack size for 8192KB

Comment: @sigmalha Is this a compiler option? For clang or GCC?

Comment: It depends on the OS (there are many different versions of Unix) and the developer tools you're using.

Comment: @MartinJames The lld documentation doesn't seem very clear to me

Comment: Unclear linker documentation?  Who would believe that?   :)

Comment: @MartinJames It must my bad. I'm fairly a greenhand and don't know how to read documentations. :(

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18909395/how-do-i-increase-the-stack-size-when-compiling-with-clang-on-os-x) help you?

Comment: @Purag **Very** helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @sunqingyao - lol, ALL linker documentation is unclear somewhere, no matter how experienced you are.  It's a fact of life, like compiler error messages bearing no relationship to the actual error:)