# How do I use the stack but avoid a stack overflow in C++

Tags: c++, macos, stack-overflow, exc-bad-access

I'm presently moving back to C++ from Java.  There are some areas of C++ where higher performance can be achieved by doing more computation on the stack.And some recursive algorithms operate more efficiently on the stack than on the heap.

Obviously the stack is a resource, and if I am going to use it, I should ensure that I do not consume too much (to the point of crashing my program).

I'm running Xcode, and wrote the following simple program:

```
#include <csignal>
static bool interrupted = false;

long stack_test(long limit){
    if((limit>0)&&(interrupted==false))
       return stack_test(limit-1)+1; // program crashes here with EXC_BAD_ACCESS...
    else
        return 0;
}

void signal_handler(int sig){
    interrupted = true;
}

int main(char* args[]){
    signal(SIGSEGV,&signal_handler);
    stack_test(1000000);
    signal(SIGSEGV,SIG_DFL);
}
```

The documentation states that running on BSD, stack limits can be checked by using `getrlimit()` and that when the stack limit is being reached, a `SIGSEGV` event is issued.  I tried installing the above event handler for this event, but instead, my program stops at the next iteration with `EXT_BAD_ACCESS (code=2,` ...`)`.

Am I taking the wrong approach here, or is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe 1000000 is not enough? Have you tried to increase it? Anyway, I would use iteration instead of recursion in your case.

Comment: 1. You can't continue iterate the recursion after stack overflow. 2. you can change the stack size by passing argument to the linker, if you use gcc look here:(at the accepted answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214363/increase-stack-size-in-os-x-lion.

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something or are you just curious? There's little point in catching that signal since there isn't much you can do when it happens.

Comment: I'm trying to elegantly handle the overflow...  by breaking out of the recursion `(interupted==false)` will no longer hold true, and the stack will be unstacked...

Comment: I believe you can't do that since signals are asynchronous.  They will be sent/captured/processed after your above code has already tried to access the forbidden memory.

Comment: Also, no C++ programmer that I know of worries about the stack dynamically.  If more stack space is needed for an application they extend it at compile/link time via compiler/linker options.

Comment: I'm thinking about stack heavy algorithms, that would take multiple branches... when the stack is depleted, it would dump where it is on the heap, to come back to later.

Answer (score 2):

This has the same problem in Java as it does in c++. You are way over-committing to the stack.

> And some recursive algorithms operate more efficiently on the stack than on the heap.

Indeed, and they are commonly of the divide and conquer type. 
The usefulness of recursion is to reduce the computation to a more manageable computation with each call.  `limit - 1` is not such a candidate.

If your question is only about the signal, I unfortunately can't offer you any advice on your system.

Comment: Agreed that the computation should be reduced, but here I am deliberately trying to handle or pre-empt the overflow condition (otherwise how do I set my boundaries?)

Comment: I think my debugger is at fault here.  The EXC_BAD_ACCESS is a Mach Microkernel exception which the (de)bugger(!) is hooking into, which is getting processed before the BSD layer generates the signal.  Though debugging a signal handler without a debugger doesn't seem like fun...

Answer (score 1):

Your signal handler can't do much to fix the stack overflow. Setting your `interrupted` flag doesn't help. When your signal handler returns, the instruction that tried to write to an address beyond the end of the stack resumes and it's still going to attempt to write beyond the end of the stack. Your code won't get back to the part which checks your `interrupted` flag.

With great care and a lot of architecture-specific code, your signal handler could potentially change the context of the thread which encountered the signal such that, when it resumes, it will be at a different point in the code.

You could also use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` to accomplish this at a coarser granularity.

A different approach would be to set up a thread to use a stack that your code allocated, using `pthread_attr_setstackaddr()` and `pthread_attr_setstacksize()` prior to `pthread_create()`. You would run your code in that secondary thread and not the main one. You could set the last page or two of the stack you allocated to be non-writable using `mprotect()`. Then, your signal handler could set the `interrupted` flag and also set those pages to be writable. That should give you enough headroom that the resumed code can execute without re-raising the signal, get far enough to check the flag, and return gracefully. Note that this is a one-time last resort, unless you can find a good point to set those guard pages non-writable again.

Comment: agreed. `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` appear to be the way to go to improve the granularity.

Comment: When would C++ throw a stack_overflow exception? - which would be more elegant than using `setjmp()` and `long jump()`?

Comment: One thought about architecture specific code: could one simply check the stack pointer, and where the stack is allocated to figure out 'how much stack is left?'  That way one could avoid the exception handling after hitting the boundary.